# C# syntax ?? in control statement

Tags: c#

Hi I have some code here which I dont understand

```
  public ObservableCollection<Packet> Items
    {
        get
        {
            this.items = this.items ?? this.LoadItems();
            return this.items;
        }
    }
```

What does the ?? means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`??` is the null-coalescing operator. The value on the left is returned as long as it is not null. If it is null, then the value on the right is returned.

```
a = b ?? c;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if (b != null)
    a = b;
else
    a = c;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

It says; assign `items` to `items` unless `items` is null, in which case, call `LoadItems` and assign the result.  It is shorthand for

```
if( this.items == null )
    this.items = this.LoadItems();

return this.items;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `??` operator returns the left-hand operand if it is not null, or else it returns the right operand.

[Reference.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173224%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's called the "null-coalescing operator", and is documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx.